# Set required attribute for an input element if it's not hidden

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I'm working on a dynamic form using angular.js.
Inputs field

```
<div ng-show="condition()">
    <input type="text" name="field" required>
</div>
```

If condition() returns false, the input field won't be shown.
But by clicking on a submit button, I'll get on chrome, the message:

```
An invalid form control with name='field' is not focusable.
```

Well, a solution is, to use ng-required:

```
<div ng-show="condition()">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-required="condition()">
</div>
```

Well, here I have to repeat code, using the condition() several times.

It becomes bad, when you can encapsulated ng-show's:

```
<div ng-show="condition1()">
    <div ng-show="condition2()">
        <input type="text" name="field"
            ng-required="condition1() && condition2()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way, the required tag should be there when the input is visible, and not, if it's hidden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using ng-show , use ng-if, because when you use ng-show then that element is still part of DOM.

something like this:

```
<div ng-if="condition()">
    <input type="text" name="field" required>
</div>
```

This way you will not get error

```
An invalid form control with name='field' is not focusable.
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a variable instead of calling a function.

```
<div ng-show="condition1()">
<div ng-show="condition2()">
    <input type="text" name="field"
        ng-required="isRequired">
</div>
```

and in your controller, you can set the isRequired variable to true or false in your condition1() and/or condition2() functions.

```
function myController($scope){
  $scope.isRequired = false;  // initialize it

  $scope.condition1 = condition1;
  $scope.condition2 = condition2;

  function condition1(){
    var returnValue = false;
    // Do some testing that sets returnValue true or false    
    $scope.isRequired = returnValue;
    return returnValue;
  }

  function condition2(){
    var returnValue = false;
    // Do some testing that sets returnValue true or false    
    $scope.isRequired = returnValue;
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

Obviously this is not bullet-proof code.  But it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you need to use `ng-if` which will remove the element from form or you can say DOM if condition is not satiesfied. you code will become like

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field"
            ng-if="condition1() && condition2()" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using ng-if instead of ng-show, that's the solution. see above

Comment: @Artisan72 did you checked the time..when I added answer..exactly 3 mins earlier than you